# Does anyone know how to solve CORS issues with React Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am trying to make Postman work with React JS using express. I am following a Mern Stack Development tutorial in free code camp. I have Cors extension enabled in my browsers, both in Chrome and in Edge. I keep getting this message in localhost:5000 "Cannot get /" and get this message {"msg":"This is CORS-enabled for an allowed domain."} in localhost:5000/users/add. My code looks something like this:
This is my server.js

```
   const express = require('express');
    const cors = require('cors');
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');

    require('dotenv').config();

    const app = express();
    const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;


   app.use(cors());
   app.use(express.json());
   const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
   mongoose.connect(uri,{useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex:true, useUnifiedTopology:true});

   const connection= mongoose.connection;
   connection.once('open', () =>{
    console.log("Mongodb database connection established successfully");
   })

   const exercisesRouter= require('./routes/exercises');
   const usersRouter= require('./routes/users');

   var allowlist = ['http://localhost:5000']
   var corsOptionsDelegate = function (req, callback) {
   var corsOptions;
   if (allowlist.indexOf(req.header('Origin')) !== -1) {
    corsOptions = { origin: true } // reflect (enable) the requested origin in the CORS response
   } else {
     corsOptions = { origin: false } // disable CORS for this request
   }
   callback(null, corsOptions) // callback expects two parameters: error and options
   }


   app.use('./exercises',exercisesRouter);
   app.use('./users', usersRouter);

   app.get('/users/add', cors(corsOptionsDelegate), function (req, res, next) {
    res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for an allowed domain.'})
   })
   app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`);
   }); 
   app.listen(80, function () {
    console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
   })
```

Comment: you are responding with `res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for an allowed domain.'})` for endpoint `/users/add`. Thats why you are seeing that response. Cors is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

## cords don’t have anything to do with this

Can you tell me where is yow route for “/“ something like this

```
app.get(“/“, (req,res)=>{
…..
});
```

Yes exactly. You don’t have it. If the route/endPoint is not declared how do use expect them browsers to show you some else
When browssers open yow link at localhost:5000
They make a get request to “/“. So express just tell’em
Can not get “/“
I do not